# How to return the value of SELECT COUNT in C

Tags: mysql, c

Well I was wondering if it is possible to use the result of count counts in a printf.

I have a code that does the count in mysql.

```
void count_sql(void) {

    if (SQL_ENTER == SQL_ROWS(mysql, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `login_client` WHERE `ID` < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)"))
        sqldebug(mysql);

    printf("Counted users\n");
    return;
}
```

I wanted to return the count value by leaving the message as below for example:

**printf("150 users were found\n");**

Comment: give count(*) an alias, execute to execute the scalar return and set it to a variable the do the if on the variable, and then the printf of the variable, I've never use sql in c so I can't give an example

Comment: I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: are you using mysql C API library? if so I could try some testing and try to help some more

Comment: @user3299379, yes I'm using. I tried to do so `int value = 0;
if (SQL_ENTER == SQL_ROWS(mysql, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS %d FROM login_client WHERE ID < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)", value)) 
printf("Counted %d users\n", value);` But returns me value 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find a data type similar to `SQL_ENTER` so I'm not sure if this is a variable or not in your code, here is the documentation I was looking at

[26.8.7 C API Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-functions.html)
below I included my `int main` but you should be able to use just the `void count_sql`, also worth noting I passed the `MYSQL` object to the fucntion this could have also been part of your issue.

also worth noting I built and tested this code on a windows environment using MinGW compiler and the mysql-connector-c-6.1.9-win32 library so it might not work in your environment

```
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mysql.h>

int main(){
    /* initialize MYSQL connection */
    MYSQL *mysql = mysql_init(NULL);

    if(mysql == NULL){
        sqldebug(mysql);
    }

    /* pass credentials here */
    if(mysql_real_connect(mysql, "localhost", "user", "password", "database", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        sqldebug(mysql);
    }

    /* run query and count results */
    count_sql(mysql);

    /*close connection and exit void*/
    mysql_close(mysql);
    exit(0);
}

void sqldebug(MYSQL *mysql)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql));
  mysql_close(mysql);
  exit(1);
}

void count_sql(MYSQL *mysql){
    /* run query */
    if(mysql_query(mysql, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `login_client` WHERE `ID` < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)")){
        sqldebug(mysql);
    }

    /* store the results */
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysql);

    if(result == NULL){
        finish_with_error(mysql);
    }

    /* check the result has records ** don't really need this part */
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    if(num_fields<1){
        printf("no fields returned");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* row record */
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    if(row=mysql_fetch_row(result)){
       printf("Counted users %s\n", row[0]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What if there is no `WHERE` clause? I.e., you just want to know the number of rows in the table? MySQL is puking *`Error: Not unique table/alias`* with no where clause, but it is exactly what I want???

Comment: I don't think excluding the where should not cause the issue, my best guess on that error would be double check the table name. If you're still having issues you should probably make a new question.